# WordPress Export/Translate/Import Single Pages

Tags: wordpress, import, export, file-format, machine-translation

Back story:

My company has recently expanded into other countries and requires the site have multiple iterations with different translations and the user be redirected based on their geolocation. I manage our public facing website which is part of the marketing department (no other developers on the team but me). Our website is a custom WordPress template that I inherited, originally developed by a third-party agency. Our parent global company has a relationship with a company called Language Wire, who will take files of many formats and translate them by hand to ensure quality, and then return them translated. In this case they will accept .html and .xml files. Before we get into a workflow of sending and receiving files regularly, they wanted me to send them some test files which they will machine translate quickly and send back to me so we can make sure the workflow will be smooth.

Issues:

I did a WordPress export (which I've never done before) and I believe it exported our entire site in the form of an .xml file but I'm not sure what this file really is. Their machine translation translated a lot of dependencies that needed to remain in english which broke the file and disallowed me from importing back in but I'm assuming their agents who do manual translations will be able to navigate this better so I'm going to ask them to do a manual translation as a test. However, I'm wondering if there is a better way to export single pages or groups of single pages and then import them back in after translation without losing the template so I can send them a smaller file to manually translate.

Anyone have experience with this kind of situation? I'm also researching geolocation redirect plugins and have no idea how I'm going to organize the subdirectories of translated versions of our site. My main issue right now though is exporting and importing wordpress pages. Thanks!

Comment: **Don't trust WP's export/import tools.** I've NEVER known them to work properly!!  Personally I like the [qTranslate-X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) plugin for doing multilingual websites. It keeps all of your post data in the same post, so there's no duplication and makes keeping track of it all much simpler. Yes, it's a bit old and creaky at the moment, but it works and there is an [effort to revive it](https://github.com/qtranslate/qtranslate-xt) that I have every confidence in.

Comment: @PeterHvD do you have an export/import tool you recommend?

Comment: Not really. Last time I tried it with the WP tools it brought in the post text but completely messed up the images! I fixed it all by hand.